# Htaccess url rewrite -stripping the large url to user friendly one

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I have link say http://www.domain.com/index.php?route=page/view&id=cs-schedule

I want to rewrite the same to http://www.domain.com/page/view/id/cs-schedule

how it is made possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ main.php?route=$1&id=$2
```

Comment: @OxJoke is working fine. But the css and images files are not picking..

Comment: what I change in the code is like this

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pillais
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?route=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

when I click the link contact us from the home page the url appearing as http://localhost/pillais/page/view/&id=contact-pillais-academy in that page css as well as image it is not picking.
And also from the same page (http://localhost/pillais/page/view/&id=contact-pillais-academy) when I click another link course overview the url is appearing as

Comment: http://localhost/pillais/page/view/page/view/&id=courses-overview

Comment: Your help is much appreciated @OxJoke

Comment: css as well as the image problems I had solved by using the absolute paths  files. Another problem still arises , page/view is append to url  like this localhost/pillais/page/view/page/view/&id=courses-overview and clicks on the next page it is coming as localhost/pillais/page/view/page/view/&id=vision-and-mission it is not the correct link. Manually typing the url http://localhost/pillais/page/view/&id=vision-and-mission then it works fine. Your help is much appreciated @OxJoke